# Rebased / relocated System.Runtime.Serialization assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I need to minimize Private WS memory for running in Citrix / Terminal Services environment. Looking at my process in vmmap, the highest Private WS image (about 1 MB) is `System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll`. By highlighting relocated DLL's in Process Explorer, I can see that this dll has been rebased. My understanding is that rebased native images can't be shared, thus the high Private WS. Also, when running on Win7 it is not rebased (due to ASLR) and the Private WS is only 32 KB.

I created a simple .Net console app with no references other than `System.Runtime.Serialization.dll` -- it is still rebased and its Private WS is 1 MB. Dumpbin.exe shows its image base is `79530000 (79530000 to 7961FFFF)`. I don't see what it's conflicting with. The closest images are loaded at:

```
790C0000 - mscorlib.dll (790C0000 to 79519FFF according to dumpbin)
79E70000 - mscorwks.dll
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you would want to do that?

Comment: I am trying to minimize Private WS for running in Citrix / Terminal Services. Looking at the Image memory use in VMMap, most System assemblies have 90-95% of the Total WS allocated as Shareable WS and 5-10% as Private WS. Only System.Runtime.Serialization is 85% Private WS. This is also the only System asm that is rebased. My understanding is that if a native image is rebased it cannot be shared. So if I can get it to load at its preferred address I will save 1 MB of Private WS memory.

Comment: Edited question to clarify purpose and add more info.

Comment: If WS is so tight you'll have wider problems, the system will have almost no cache so performance will be poor. Quicker and, probably cheaper (given cost of developers) to have more RAM in the system.

Answer (score 1):

[`al.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex.aspx) can be used to set an assembly's load address (option `/base[address]`).

However unless you have a performance problem when loading (and control enough of the loaded assemblies), then this is unlikely to make any difference.

Comment: See above, I think it would make a difference to Private WS. But I think al.exe can't be used to modify existing assemblies, see [this answer/comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/789115/281650).

Comment: @JMH You could try using the Window's SDK's `rebase.exe` but my understanding is that it won't work (and you'll also need to modify something in the GAC, which is breaking the integrity of .NET.