# Adding / Replacing resources after building C# application

Tags: c#

I have a C# application which has exe files and scripts stored as embedded resources in a .resx file.

I'm trying to find a way to replace the embedded resources without a full rebuild. This way I would just have to swap out scripts or executables when they are versioned instead of doing a full rebuild.

So far I've found [several tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_%28Windows%29) which can add and replace resources (satellite resources?) to the executable, but I haven't been able to access those resources in my C# application.

So far I've only found a way to access embedded resources, the ones I attach after the build don't show up.

```
        // This only retrieves the contents of embedded .resx files
        System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
        thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

        // List files in .resx of known name.
        ResourceSet rs = <my resource>.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
        Dictionary<string, object> resources = rs.Cast<DictionaryEntry>().ToDictionary(r => (string)r.Key, r => r.Value);

        foreach (string key in resources.Keys)
            Console.WriteLine(key);
```

Comment: Resources are meant to be static for the life of the application, if you are using scripts (text based) and exe files, I would just keep them in normal files. If you want to protect them from being modified you can always encrypt/decrypt them when you want to run them. Modifying Resx files is a pain because it requires additional components to be installed on the client machine (you don't notice because you have Visual Studio).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, these files are static after the executable has been released. I just want to be able to replace some of them before releasing in case of last minute script changes.

Comment: Is this question still valid? Have you found an answer? I'm currently trying something similar. *(Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/783885/2826535))*. I know how to read the embedded (satellite?) resources, but I have no idea how to add it outside of Visual Studio. To read the embedded assembly you need to use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(string name)` function. But you probably can not access this assembly as a standard resource, only as a binary file. But you can load another DLL and read resources by a function from the embedded DLL.